# Android layout restructure

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen-support

I am trying to create a fragment layout to hold the user information.

**current layout xml.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/userInfo">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/profileHolder"
        android:background="@drawable/bluelayer"
        android:layout_weight="0">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="95dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/spacer1"></LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="350dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/profilePicHolder"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/circle">

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:id="@+id/profilePic"
                    android:src="@drawable/profilepic"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:paddingTop="20dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="95dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/spacer2"></LinearLayout>
        </TableRow>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:id="@+id/gap"></LinearLayout>

   <ScrollView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:padding="5dp">

       <TableLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent">

           <TableRow
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:background="#f2f0f0"
               android:paddingTop="5dp"
               android:paddingBottom="5dp">

               <RelativeLayout
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:layout_gravity="center">

                   <ImageView
                       android:layout_width="30dp"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:id="@+id/mailIcon"
                       android:src="@drawable/mailiconoriginal"
                       android:paddingRight="3dp" />

                   <TextView
                       android:layout_width="320dp"
                       android:layout_height="40dp"
                       android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mailIcon"
                       android:id="@+id/info_email"
                       android:ems="10"
                       android:textSize="15sp"
                       android:paddingTop="5dp"
                       android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                       android:padding="5dp"
                       android:layout_span="2" />
               </RelativeLayout>

           </TableRow>

           <TableRow
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_marginTop="3dp"></TableRow>

           <TableRow
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:background="#d8d5d5"
               android:paddingTop="5dp"
               android:paddingBottom="5dp">

               <RelativeLayout
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent">
                   <ImageView
                       android:layout_width="30dp"
                       android:layout_height="40dp"
                       android:id="@+id/phoneIcon"
                       android:src="@drawable/phoneiconoriginal"
                       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                       android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                       android:paddingRight="3dp" />

                   <TextView
                       android:layout_width="320dp"
                       android:layout_height="40dp"
                       android:id="@+id/info_phone"
                       android:ems="10"
                       android:textSize="15sp"
                       android:paddingTop="5dp"
                       android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                       android:padding="5dp"
                       android:layout_span="2"
                       android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                       android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
               </RelativeLayout>
           </TableRow>

           <TableRow
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_marginTop="1dp"></TableRow>

           <TableRow
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:paddingTop="3dp"
               android:paddingBottom="3dp">

               <RelativeLayout
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent">

                   <ImageView
                       android:layout_width="30dp"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:id="@+id/userIcon"
                       android:src="@drawable/namelogo"
                       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                       android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                       android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/info_firstName"
                       android:paddingRight="3dp"
                       android:background="#a8a8a8" />

                   <TextView
                       android:layout_width="150dp"
                       android:layout_height="45dp"
                       android:id="@+id/info_firstName"
                       android:ems="10"
                       android:textSize="15sp"
                       android:paddingTop="5dp"
                       android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                       android:padding="5dp"
                       android:layout_span="2"
                       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                       android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/userIcon"
                       android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/userIcon"
                       android:background="#a8a8a8" />

                   <LinearLayout
                       android:orientation="horizontal"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="match_parent"
                       android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                       android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                       android:id="@+id/splitter"
                       android:background="#FFFFFF"
                       android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/info_firstName"
                       android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/info_firstName"></LinearLayout>

                   <TextView
                       android:layout_width="150dp"
                       android:layout_height="45dp"
                       android:id="@+id/info_lastName"
                       android:ems="10"
                       android:textSize="15sp"
                       android:paddingTop="5dp"
                       android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                       android:padding="5dp"
                       android:layout_span="2"
                       android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                       android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                       android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/splitter"
                       android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/splitter"
                       android:background="#a8a8a8" />

               </RelativeLayout>
           </TableRow>
       </TableLayout>
   </ScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

**I don't want to make multiple xml files for different screen sizes**.Can someone help me with the layout.

[image: userinfo]

Comment: So whats the issue you are facing with current layout?

Comment: On different screen sizes the last row is not filling completely.The problem is with the last row in the scroll view.Do i need to make multiple xml files or is their a way to use this layout only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one, you need to use `layout_weight` to make it compatible to all devices, here is your solution

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/userInfo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/profileHolder"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="@drawable/bluelayer"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/spacer1"
                    android:layout_width="95dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/profilePicHolder"
                    android:layout_width="350dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/circle"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/profilePic"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:paddingTop="20dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/profilepic" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/spacer2"
                    android:layout_width="95dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>
            </TableRow>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/gap"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#f2f0f0"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/mailIcon"
                            android:layout_width="30dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingRight="3dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/mailiconoriginal" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/info_email"
                            android:layout_width="320dp"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:layout_span="2"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mailIcon"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                            android:paddingTop="5dp"
                            android:textSize="15sp" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#d8d5d5"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/phoneIcon"
                            android:layout_width="30dp"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                            android:paddingRight="3dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/phoneiconoriginal" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/info_phone"
                            android:layout_width="320dp"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_span="2"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                            android:paddingTop="5dp"
                            android:textSize="15sp" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </TableRow>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/userIcon"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/info_firstName"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                            android:background="#a8a8a8"
                            android:paddingRight="3dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/namelogo" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/info_firstName"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="45dp"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                            android:layout_span="2"
                            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/userIcon"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/userIcon"
                            android:background="#a8a8a8"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                            android:paddingTop="5dp"
                            android:textSize="15sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/splitter"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/info_firstName"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/info_firstName"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="#FFFFFF"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/info_lastName"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="45dp"
                            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_span="2"
                            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/splitter"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/splitter"
                            android:background="#a8a8a8"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                            android:paddingTop="5dp"
                            android:textSize="15sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>


                </LinearLayout>
            </TableLayout>
        </ScrollView>


    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use different methods to achieve it.

1. you can create different layouts for different resolutions.
2. you can create different dimen folders for different resolution.

inside values --default

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="width">100dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

values-mdpi 
values-sw320dp
values-sw480dp
values-sw600dp
values-sw720dp

Define different width in all these folders and from main layout

android:layout_width="@dimen/width"